# Можно ли как-то "перегрузить фигурные скобки"?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Недавно начал изучать STL в C++. В ней есть класс vector, то что, как мне говорили, является "прокаченным динамическим массивом".

```
vector<int> arr = { 34, 654, 98, 12 };
```

Таким образом можно передать сразу в массив значения через фигурные скобки. 
А как такую вещь можно реализовать самостоятельно в своих классах? Можно ли как-то "перегрузить фигурные скобки"?

Comment: это не перегрузка скобок, а конструктор принимающий `std::initializer_list`

Comment: Понятно, прошу прощения за невнимательность.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В С++ перегружаются функции и операторы, а фигурные скобки ни тем ни другим не являются - в данном случае они служат в качестве инициализатора для объекта типа `std::vector`, который должен определить конструктор принимающий `std::initializer_list` (как уже сказали в комментариях).

Пример с пользовтельским типом (или классом)

```
class X {
    std::vector<int> m_v; 

public:
    X(std::initializer_list<int> v)
        : m_v(v) 
    {} 
};

X x{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Также стоит добавить, что такая инициализация доступа в компиляторах поддерживающих как минимум С++11.

Comment: @acade Элементы в `initializer_list` всегда константные, так что по идее должно быть без разницы. Но я бы убрал `&&` (стандартные контейнеры принимают `initializer_list` по значению.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а как же хороший стиль? хотя по-большому счету - без разницы